# Does the Pathfinder Soul Knife's weapon dissipate if it has Returning?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, psionics

I understand that you may add enhancements and abilities to your soul knife, and it says that you may throw your soul knife at lvl 2. I'm wondering, if I put the Returning ability on my soul knife, will it still dissipate?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, yes, the mind blade dissipates, but even if it didn’t, *returning* would be pointless on a mind blade anyway: by the time you can get it on there (requiring at least +2 worth of enhance mind blade, since you have to put the minimum +1 before adding *returning*), you’re 5th level, which means you get the quick draw ability. *Returning* would have a thrown weapon return to your hand by the start of your next turn. Quick draw allows you to create a new mind blade as a free action once per round. So you can just throw the mind blade, and then on your next turn create a new one: you still have a mind blade, the same as you would with *returning*. So *returning* is a wasted property on a mind blade.

Comment: Ooohh okay. Thanks alot! Also, whats your opinion on the Soul Knife class? If any.

Comment: @TropicPatty51 Despite extensive efforts on DSP’s part (and note that I have worked freelance for DSP and consider the people there good friends), the soulknife is still an atrociously lackluster class. The [psychic armory](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XZ7YUgvH7vgDqJvJs8vaQYCPV6K6wh8YAbW_ElFUHX4/edit?usp=sharing), [war soul](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/soulknife/archetypes/dreamscarred-press/war-soul-soulknife-archetype), and [living legend](http://dreamscarred.com/product/psionics-augmented-living-legend-pdf/) archetypes, though, are pretty solid.

Comment: @TropicPatty51 Ultimately, the problem with the soulknife, and most of its archetypes, is that “I have a magic sword” is *not* a special ability. Every warrior in the game has a magic sword. Sure, they had to pay for it—but they have *real class features you can’t buy* from their class, which are always better than things you can buy.

Comment: @TropicPatty51: that's a whole 'nother question, and on which the Q/A format isn't terribly well-suited to answer. A question comparing the relative abilities of a Soul Knife vs., say, a Fighter is more likely to get a good answer (eg., "how does the Soul Kinfe's Mind Blade ability stack up to the Fighter's Weapon Training?"), as might questions about particularly good builds - especially if there's a particular niche you're trying to fill (eg., "how can my Soul Knife best deal with an undead-heavy setting?"). So might something like "Why do people say the Soul Knife is lackluster?".

Comment: To complement, at 14th level you can learn Multiple Throw, which allows you to throw a number of times per round as attacks you can make with your  mind blade.